# How to separate the Listview with Check and Uncheck items Android?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

In a Scrollview i have a listview with Textview and checkbox in every listitem, i want to show the item check and uncheck separately inside a same listview, with different layouts 1.Active with uncheck items and 2.finished with checked items.Can anyone find the solution.

1.Layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollVie2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="570dp" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="476dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.67"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Finished"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your code like this..here i am displaying a imageview and checkbox..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {
    if (convertview == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertview = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.images_gridview, null);
    }
    ImageView gridImage = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.image);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox.setTag(position);
    if (photos.get(position).isSelected()) {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int width;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    } else {
        Point point = new Point();
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        width = point.x;
    }

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width / 3, width / 3);
    gridImage.setLayoutParams(params);
    gridImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(photos.get(position)
            .getThumbnilImageUrl()));
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkedButton,
                boolean checked) {
            if (checked) {
                selectedPhotos.add(photos.get((Integer) checkedButton
                        .getTag()));
                photos.get((Integer) checkedButton.getTag()).setSelected(
                        true);
            } else {
                selectedPhotos.remove(photos.get((Integer) checkedButton
                        .getTag()));
                photos.get((Integer) checkedButton.getTag()).setSelected(
                        false);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertview;
}
```

Comment: if (photos.get(position).isSelected()) instead of photos what i want to write!!i m new to android..

Comment: For you its not required if you maintaing any class objects then it is required..for maintaing listitems which have selected and non selected maintain one class with two variables one string and one boolean value..set string to your listview textvitew..change the boolean when selected